# as long as I know

Tags: grammar

Is this correct to say so with reflexive if not why?

> "As long as I know ***myself***, I always get in trouble"
>
> "As long as I know ***myself***, I've never been a good player"
>
> "As long as I know ***him***, he never play football"
>
> "As long as I know ***him***, he always dissatisfied with anything

Comment: You might need to be more specific about your question.  Are you asking specifically about whether the reflexive should be used there, or what?  (Your sentences are not idiomatic for a variety of reasons, but I'm not sure which part you're asking about.

Comment: The second example is definitely incorrect. I suggest "He has never played football as long as I **have known** him". The first example is incomplete, it could be continued as, for example "As long as I know myself, I can make the right choices." But if it is intended to be used like the second example, it is wrong.

Comment: If you're talking about the question in your title, I'd say there's a mismatch between the pronouns - "As long as one knows oneself" would work better (though also sound like you're pretending to be royalty).

Comment: @Showsni haha yes, so what would work better is "As long as I know myself". OP hasn't yet pretended to be royalty:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"As long as" has more than one meaning, highly dependent on the tense it's used with.

"As long as" + *present simple* usually means, "provided that". So your example sentences mean, "***Provided that** I know him*...", which makes almost no sense.

"As long as" + *present perfect* has the meaning you're looking for, which is "***For the whole time that** I have known him*"

Answer (score -2):

No, it’s not correct.

“As long as I’ve known him, he never plays football.”

If this is the template sentence you’re using for reference, then “As long as I’ve known oneself” sounds odd because “oneself” is for referring to the same person - like, “As long as one has known oneself, there are things that have remained constant.”

Comment: I think "... **he's** never **played** football" is much more idiomatic.